Как получить кадр видео по ссылке?
У меня есть вопрос, он очень сложный, но всё-таки. Делаю видео-плеер, на Python. Есть конечно специальная библиотека, для разрезки видео на кадры. Но её у меня не получается установить. Увидел в ролике, что человек через ссылку получает кадр видео. Как получить такую ссылку? Мне нужно, чтобы в ссылке было не видео, а изображение в виде кадра, который указан в ссылке. По ссылке я конечно смогу закинуть изображение в tkinter (это новое окно от Python'а), но, вопрос в строении этой ссылки:
Будет типа https://service/page/content/video?frame=1, или как?

зависит от видеосервера. некоторые имеют ссылку на предпросмотр.
в общем случае надо качать кусок видео и вырезать оттуда кадр.
